# How to predict the number of comparisons done by QuickSort if you know the percentage to which the array is pre-sorted?

Tags: quicksort

I've noticed that correlating the number of comparisons done by a naive implementation of QuickSort with the percentage of elements that were already sorted gives you a curly-brace-shaped-curve if you use logarithmic scale:
[image: Curly-brace-shaped curve]
So, how can this curly-brace-shaped curve be mathematically described (the red curve represents the behavior of the c++ "sort" function, and it appears much more complicated)? If it can be done precisely, then one can precisely predict how many comparisons QuickSort would do simply by passing through the array, counting the number of elements for which array[i]<array[i+1], and inserting that number into a formula. I've tried to find a mathematical formula that approximates that using a genetic algorithm, here is what I ended up with:

```
f(n,s)=exp((ln(n)+ln(ln(n)))*1.05+(ln(n)-ln(ln(n)))*0.83*abs(2.38854*pow(s,7)-0.284258*pow(s,6)-1.87104*pow(s,5)+0.372637*pow(s,4)+0.167242*pow(s,3)-0.0884977*pow(s,2)+0.315119*s))
```

Here, 'f' signifies the number of comparisons done by QuickSort, 'n' signifies the number of elements in the array and 's' signifies the proportion of the elements that are already sorted: it's -1 if the array is reverse-sorted, 1 if it's already sorted, and approximately 0 if it's randomly shuffled.

Can you come up with a better formula?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "naive" implementation? How are you choosing the pivot element?

Comment: @Tassle, The first element is always the pivot.

Comment: Well this at least explains the slowness in the sorted or reverse-sorted cases, as then your algorithm would do $\Theta(n^2/2)$ comparisons while it does $O(n\log n)$ comparisons in the average case. A complete closed formula relating your metric of "sortedness" with the average runtime seems hard to derive however. Probably too hard for me at least.

Comment: Please add to your answer the exact algorithm you’re using, and how you measure sortedness. The latter is mentioned in your answer, but not explicitly. Also, what is your target function? It seems to be the expected number of comparisons over a uniformly random permutation with given amount of sortedness.